# Como exibir a duração de um video do bd com a extensão getid3?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

```
<?php
 Include ("getid3/getid3.php");

 $filename="nome_do_video.mp4";
 $getID3 = new getID3;
 $file = $getID3->analize($filename);
 echo $file['playtime_string'];

 ?>
```

So que quando tento puxar do banco de dados não consigo, por exemplo o caminho do video que ta salvo no bd ta assim `"videos/files/nomedovideo.mp4"`.

Como eu poderia exibir o caminho na parte do `$filename="nome_do_vídeo.mp4"`;

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Seja bem vindo Gabriel, por favor formata o código por que está um pouco dificil de ler.

Comment: Pronto agora da pra entender.

Comment: `"videos/files/nomedovideo.mp4"` é o caminho relativo, diga-me qual é o caminho absoluto para a pasta videos?

Comment: Quando eu faço o upload do video ele é salvo na pasta videos/files/ e salva no banco de dados o caminho do video que é videos/files/nomedovideo.mp4 eu queria que o script reconhe ce se o caminho do video do banco de dados porque se eu especificar manualmente o caminho do video ele funciona  ex: $filename = "videos/files/nomedovideo.mp4"; como eu poderia fazer para q o script reconhecer o caminho do video?

Comment: Então, o problema é que se o script estiver em uma pasta diferente do level relativo a pasta "video". Por isto quando rodamos um script o melhor é usar o caminho absoluto ao invés do caminho relativo. Diz uma coisa, como você está pegando os dados do banco?

Comment: <?php
 Include ("getid3/getid3.php");
 $getID3 = new getID3;
 $file = $getID3->analize($videosrc);
 echo $file['playtime_string'];

 ?> sendo $videosrc é o valor do caminho do banco de dados exe. $videosrc = row ['file_location']; so que da erro na verificação do caminho

Comment: Gabriel `row ['file_location']` está errado o certo é `$row ['file_location']`

Comment: Mais mesmo assim ainda não consegui fazer o script exibir a duração do video do bd

Comment: se você fizer assim `echo ':', $row ['file_location'], ':';` o que é exibido na tela?

Comment: mesmo da erro na verifcaçao do arquivo mais dexa queto eu vou fazer em ffmpeg ai eu pego a duração do video no upload e salvo no bd ai depois eu so dou um echo na variável mais mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Mas o que o `echo` mostra na tela? ele mostra exatamente o que está no banco?